# Transformer output does not agree with formulas

Tags: transformer, zvs

I built my own step-up transformer to be driven using a ZVS using a core from a flyback transformer in order to charge some 450 V capacitors. I wanted to see how well my transformer operated with a load on the secondary side and that's when I discovered an issue. With a 6.8 \$\Omega\$ resistor across the secondary I measured this on the oscilloscope. [image]

It looked fine to me so I would expect around 2.4 V peaks on the primary since my turn ratio is about 10. But I measured this for the voltage on the primary.

[image]

So my step-up transformer is now a step-down transformer?? I initially thought the secondary was saturating due to the relatively large current causing the secondary inductance to drop below the primary inductance thus making it a step-down transformer. So I tested a 1.2 \$k\Omega\$ across the secondary to reduce the current but it was still acting as a step down transformer this time even more (4 V peak on the secondary side). I really don't know why this is happening.

Schematic:

[image]

Update:

I tested larger values for the secondary load as suggested by Antonio51. I started with 1M\$\Omega\$ just to be safe and it all worked fine, nominal secondary voltage off 440V peak. I then went down to 100k\$\Omega\$; also worked fine. 6.6k\$\Omega\$ also worked so I decided to test my luck and tried 180\$\Omega\$. This caused the secondary voltage to drop to around 330V peaks while the primary voltage did not drop in accordance. So I think it's safe to say it works for loads above 1k\$\Omega\$ but why it doesn't for smaller loads is beyond me.

Also, just to relieve any confusion, that resistor I tested in my orginal post which I thought was 1.2k\$\Omega\$ was actually 1.2\$\Omega\$.

Comment: What was the output without the load? How many primary and secondary turns? What gauge wire?

Comment: Output with no load is 440V peak. 6 primary turns with 12 AWG.  Secondary is 105 turns with 20 AWG magnet wire.

Comment: It doesn't add up. The primary voltage is 24 volts p-p and should, on the secondary produce 420 volts p-p yet you say 440 volts peak (aka 880 volts p-p).

Comment: You may be looking at the wrong image? When loaded the secondary is 24V peak (48V p-p) not the primary. When not loaded, the primary is 42V peak (84 p-p) thus creating 420 peak (840 p-p) (in my case 440V peak becuase of extra windings)

Comment: I'm not looking at any image. I'm reading your comment and doing math on that (knowing that it is a ZVS circuit)

Comment: Well I'm lost as to why you said the primary is 24V p-p? It's not, I measured it. It's 42.4V peak (84.8V p-p) thus the secondary will output (ideally) 424V peak. It's 440V peak for me as I wound extra windings on the secondary to account for the efficiency and such.

Comment: Actually, given that the secondary is 4mH and primary is 15uH we can calculate that the ratio is closer to 16.3. I guess efficiency makes the output 440V peak? I'm just going off of what I have measured.

Comment: Your ZVS converter power supply is 12 volts.

Comment: Yes it is. About 12.4V from a car battery

Comment: What type&size core?

Comment: It's a core from a flyback used in a CRT TV. I'm not sure on material type, ferrite is the extent of my knowledge. It's about 7.6cm tall, 4.1cm wide, 1.5cm deep. If its of any help I noticed that at no secondary load the resonance frequecny is about 10kHz but with a load its about 16kHz as seen in the scope captures. So either L1 and L3 are saturating or the primary coil is. I would think it would be L1 and L3 saturating since they are smaller and have more turns. Not sure if this saturation is a problem though since the primary and secondary waveform are both pretty clean

Comment: This schematic is a induction "heater", excepted the "load". You should use a "driver" at a fixed frequency probably at 16 kHz.

Comment: You're right my setup is essentially and induction heater driving a primary instead. I think most instead use a single inductor with a center-tapped primary coil like this http://uzzors2k.com/index.php?page=capcharger2. How it is now the circuit works great for charging the caps, really quick charge time. I'm not trying to fix an issue I was just hoping to learn something by understanding why the transformer behaves unexpectedly with a load on the secondary.

Comment: I think your load is too low (strange things "may" happen, resonance frequency of secondary 4 mH) ... You quasi-short the secondary ... With a load of 100 k, I get 2 kV at the output with the values of your picture (MOSFET I use are IRF540).

Comment: Ah ok. I don't have time to try this today but I will tomorrow. Do you think 10k will be enough? I don't have high power 100k resistors

Comment: Power is then 1 kV ^2 / 100 k = 10 W.  The resistor must just withstand 2 kV ... so, ten serial resistors of 10 kOhm, 2 W, would do it. Be careful. The current may be very "dangerous".

Comment: Ok I can do that. I'll update on how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the resulting behavior for a "charging" capacitor (100 k for "safety" discharge).

Note that the peak current is somewhat "big", quasi 50 A.

Note that you can reduce the peak current with L2 & L3 bigger and coupling it, but the charge of the capacitor is slower.

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. I think I now know why the voltage drops so much with load. My orginal theory was that the secondary was saturating and the secondary inductance drops below the 15uH primary thus making the transformer step-down instead. But I tested what I thought was a 1.2k\$\Omega\$ resistor but it was actually 1.2\$\Omega\$ and thus saturating even more than the 6.8\$\Omega\$ causing even lower voltage on the secondary. But with larger resistors the current is lower and the secondary doesn't saturate as much or at all which explains why it worked fine with larger loads.